# Where do blocking I/O comes from?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing, scheduling, multitasking

My understanding is that the hardware architecture and the operating systems are designed not to block the cpu. When any kind of blocking operation needs to happen, the operating system registers an interruption and moves on to something else, making sure the precious time of the cpu is always effectively used.

It makes me wonder why most programming languages were designed with blocking APIs, but most importantly, since the operating system works in an asynchronous way when it comes to IO, registering interruptions and dealing with results when they are ready later on, I'm really puzzled about *how our programming language APIs escape this asynchrony*. How does the OS provides synchronous system calls for our programming language using blocking APIs?

Where this synchrony comes from? Certainly not at the hardware level. So, is there an infinite loop somewhere I don't know about spinning and spinning until some interruption is triggered?

Comment: Re, "spinning and spinning until some interruption" Most CPUs have an instruction that halts the processor until the next interrupt. Using that instruction in the operating system's "idle loop" can dramatically reduce the amount of power used/heat generated by a system that is not fully loaded.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo "how our programming language APIs escape this asynchrony" what do you mean by escape ?

Comment: @mightyWOZ How can the OS offer a synchronous system call for something that, by nature, is asynchronous? Where is actual source of the “blocking” nature of such system calls?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo one more question. do you think synchronous system calls are served instantly without any delay?

Comment: @mightyWOZ No, I do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observations are correct - the operating system interacts with the underlying hardware asynchronously to perform I/O requests.

The behavior of *blocking* I/O comes from threads. Typically, the OS provides threads as an abstraction for user-mode programs to use. But sometimes, green/lightweight threads are provided by a user-mode virtual machine like in Go, Erlang, Java (Project Loom), etc. If you aren't familiar with threads as an abstraction, read up on some background theory from any OS textbook.

Each thread has a state consisting of a fixed set of registers, a dynamically growing/shrinking stack (for function arguments, function call registers, and return addresses), and a next instruction pointer. The implementation of blocking I/O is that when a thread calls an I/O function, the underlying platform hosting the thread (Java VM, Linux kernel, etc.) immediately suspends the thread so that it cannot be scheduled for execution, and also submits the I/O request to the platform below. When the platform receives the completion of the I/O request, it puts the result on that thread's stack and puts the thread on the scheduler's execution queue. That's all there is to the magic.

Why are threads popular? Well, I/O requests happen in some sort of context. You don't just read a file or write a file as a standalone operation; you read a file, run a specific algorithm to process the result, and issue further I/O requests. A thread is one way to keep track of your progress. Another way is known as "continuation passing style", where every time you perform an I/O operation (A), you pass a callback or function pointer to explicitly specify what needs to happen after I/O completion (B), but the call (A) returns immediately (non-blocking / asynchronous). This way of programming asynchronous I/O is considered hard to reason about and even harder to debug because now you don't have a meaningful call stack because it gets cleared after every I/O operation. This is discussed at length in the great essay ["What color is your function?"](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/).

Note that the platform has no obligation to provide a threading abstraction to its users. The OS or language VM can very well expose an asynchronous I/O API to the user code. But the vast majority of platforms (with exceptions like Node.js) choose to provide threads because it's much easier for humans to reason about.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that the hardware architecture and the operating systems are designed not to block the cpu.

Any rationally designed operating system would have a system service interface that does what you say. However, there are many non-rational operating systems that do not work in this manner at the process level.

Blocking I/O is simpler to program than non-blocking I/O. Let me give you an example from the VMS operating system (Windoze works the same way under the covers). VMS has a system services called SYS$QIO and SYS$QIOW. That is, Queue I/O Request and Queue I/O Request and wait. The system services have identical parameters. One pair of parameters is the address of a completion routine and a parameters to that routine. However, these parameters are rarely used with SYS$QIOW.

If you do a SYS$QIO call, it returns immediately. When the I/O operation completes, the completion routine is called as a software interrupt. You then have to do interrupt programming in your application. We did this all the time. If you want your application to be able to read from 100 input streams simultaneously, this is the way you had to do it. It's just more complicated than doing simple blocking I/O with one device.

If a programming language were to incorporate such a callback system into its I/O statements, it would be mirroring VMS/RSX/Windoze. Ada uses the task concept to implement such systems in a operating-system-independent manner.

In the Eunuchs world, it was traditional to create a separate process for each device. That was simpler until you had to read AND write to each device.